# What versions of Primefaces extensions are compatible with the Primefaces 3.5?

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I would like to know what versions of Primefaces extensions are compatible with the Primefaces 3.5?

Answer (score 3):

The correct version of Primefaces extensions to use with Primefaces 3.5 is 0.7.1.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

you may use the release notes of primefaces extentions:
https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/wiki/Release-Notes

> 04.05.2013 Release 0.7.0, PrimeFaces Extensions.
>   Main release, built on top of PrimeFaces 3.5.